# css only. Click on li, show nested ul and li. Release mouse button, must continue show nested ul and li

Tags: css

If i click on navigation `a href` `li` want to display closest deeper level subcategories (`ul` and `li`). Want to do all with css (do not want to use jquery).

Using example from here http://bonrouge.com/br.php?page=cssonclickswitch

In the example, if click on link, display certain image.

Modified the example (here live example http://jsfiddle.net/w83ob3Lh/5/)

```
<ul id="cssonclickswitch" class="">

<li><a href="#n">Wine
<span><img  alt="wine" height="50" width="50"></span></a>
  <ul class="">
  <li><a href="#">Option One 1-1</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">Option One 1-2</a> </li>
  </ul> 
</li>

</ul>
```

And css this

```
#cssonclickswitch a span, #cssonclickswitch ul li {display: none;}

#cssonclickswitch a:active span, 
#cssonclickswitch a:focus span, 
#cssonclickswitch :active ul li, 
#cssonclickswitch :focus ul li 
{
display: block;
/*position: absolute;*/
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0px;
width: 50px;
color:red;
background:#fff;
}
```

So on page load `#cssonclickswitch ul li {display: none;}` This is ok.

If click on link and hold pressed mouse button see "subcategories"

```
Option One 1-1
Option One 1-2
```

Problem is. If release mouse button, then i can see image (that is ok), but subcategory disappears (not ok).

How to keep/show subcategories if mouse button is released (after click on link)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `#cssonclickswitch a:focus ~ ul li`
Updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/w83ob3Lh/6/

Comment: Seems next problem. If click on "image", nothing changes (that is ok). But if click on link (<li><a href="#">Option One 1-1</a> </li>) whole `ul` disappears. How to keep the `ul` ?